# Tic-Tac-Toe game -- Regex wants more characters than in the 3x3 board?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I have the code below for a 3x3 tic-tac-toe game. It works perfectly fine, but there are things I don't understand.

The objective of the function is to return:

- -1 if the board is not yet finished (there are empty spots),
- 1 if "X" won,
- 2 if "O" won,
- 0 if it's a cat's game (i.e. a draw).

```js
function isSolved(board) {
   board = board.join('-').replace(/,/g,'');
   if(/222|2...2...2|2....2....2|2..2..2/.test(board)) return 2;
   if(/111|1...1...1|1....1....1|1..1..1/.test(board)) return 1;
   if(/0/.test(board)) return -1;
   return 0;

}

var result = isSolved([[0, 0, 1],[0, 1, 2],[2, 1, 0]]); //board is 3 dimensional array.

console.log(result); // -1
```

I don't understand a part of the regex in the `if` statement, i.e  `1....1....1`, since the maximum input the board can take is 9; but here it seems to be 11. Why is that?

The code is absolutely fine, but I don't understand what's happening. Could you explain?

Comment: what is `.test(board)`?

Comment: @SaadAnees this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test. The syntax is `regexObj.test(str)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.` match with any character so that

`222` match with

```
-------------
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
-------------
|   |   |   |
-------------
|   |   |   |
-------------

OR

-------------
|   |   |   |
-------------
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
-------------
|   |   |   |
-------------

OR

-------------
|   |   |   |
-------------
|   |   |   |
-------------
| 2 | 2 | 2 |
-------------
```

and `2...2...2` match with

```
-------------
| 2 | . | . | . 
-------------
| 2 | . | . | . 
-------------
| 2 |   |   | 
-------------

OR

-------------
|   | 2 | . | . 
-------------
| . | 2 | . | . 
-------------
| . | 2 |   | 
-------------

OR

-------------
|   |   | 2 | . 
-------------
| . | . | 2 | . 
-------------
| . | . | 2 |
-------------
```

the `.` outside the board match with the separator `-` .

And the other two are more or less the same.

Answer (score 5):

The regex looks at 11 characters because `board` has been joined with two extra `-` characters:

```
board = board.join('-')
```

Presumably, the original `board` is a 2D array, and the commas introduced by this join (as the nested arrays are stringified in the process), are removed with:

```
.replace(/,/g,'');
```

So an original board like this:

```
[
    [1, 0, 1],
    [2, 2, 0],
    [0, 0, 0]
]
```

...is turned into a string with `.join("-")`:

```
"1,0,1-2,2,0-0,0,0"
```

...and finally cleaned of the commas:

```
"101-220-000".
```

The additional separator makes it easier to find some patterns without raising false positives. For instance, when there is a match with `222`, one can be sure that they will be in one row, and a match with `1..1..1` will likewise detect the three possible vertical 3-in-a-rows without false positives as it can only have a match that starts at position 0, 1 or 2. The `1....1....1` is 11 characters long and can only match at position 0 for one of the diagonals. Finally, `1..1..1` can also only match at one position, i.e. position 2, as otherwise one of the hyphens would conflict with a `1` in the pattern. A match represents the opposite diagonal.

#### Further improvement

One could merge two regexes into one (saving some execution time), by using a back reference, and use some logic to join all possibilities in one expression:

```
function isSolved(board) {
   board = board.join('-').replace(/,/g,'');
   var match = board.search(/([12])(\1|...\1...|....\1....|..\1..)\1/);
   return +(board[match] || board.includes("0") && -1);
}
```

Comment: @trincol thanks a lot.Your explanation made my day. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

After the `join` and `replace` operations, `board` will be a string like this:

```
001-012-210
```

Each row is separated by `-`.

The `111` case is testing for a row full of X's.

The `1...1...1` case is testing for a column full of X's. There are 3 dots because there is also the `-` character.

The `1..1..1` case is testing for a diagonal full of X's.

Answer (score 1):

In a regular expressions alternative patterns are separated by `|` and `.` matches exactly any one character.

The board in converted to a string, that looks like this:

```
001-012-210
```

That means player `1` wins, when

- they filled a row, which means the string contains the substring `111`
- they filled a column, which means the string is either
  `1xx-1xx-1xx` , `x1x-x1x-x1x` or `xx1-xx1-xx1`. In these cases there are exactly three characters between each `1`, which is matched by `1...1...1` in the regular expression.
- they filled a diagonal, which  means the string is either  `xx1-x1x-1xx` or `1xx-x1x-xx1`. In these cases there are either exactly two or four characters between each `1`, which are matched by either `1..1..1` or `1....1...1`.